# Power source with buck converter, load and supercap

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, buck, simulink

I have the following circuit created in MATLAB Simulink:[image]

I have a power source (Vfc,Rfc) on the left. Its operating point is set by using a buck converter (mosfet,diode,L,C1), which controls the current of the source. At 33Amperes, the voltage of the power source is around 30V, which gives a power of 1000W. On the right side of the circuit I connected a load, and a supercapacitor. The load is specified through its active power consumption, which is set to 800W. The supercapacitor is set to an initial voltage of 20V. From what I understand, what should happen is that the load would draw the current it needs in order to consume its 800W, and the rest of the power (~200W) would be stored to the supercapacitor. However this doesn't happen; For some reason the supercap draws a significantly larger amount of current, and as a result, the load consumes a much smaller amount of power. Any ideas?

---

Edit: I tried to use a current source. Here is the model:[image]

I used a time switch because the voltage was not initialized at start, and the divider gave an error. The concept of the current source is to force a current I = P(needed)/ V(t). I removed the supercapacitor (to simplify things) and added a simple resistor to consume the extra power provided by the main source. There is still a problem though. After switching to the measured voltage feedback, all the measurements in scope1 start oscillating, completely out of control (pick currents reach 10^5 A).

Comment: If power is continually entering the supercapacitor then the output voltage will be rising and rising until the load starts to take over as the main consumer and things should stabilize.

Comment: I understand that, but my goal is for the load to draw 800W from the start. That is why I used the Load block of simulink, and specified its active power consumption. To sum up, I need to feed my load with 800W from the start, and the rest to be stored to the supercap.

Comment: What is the purpose of the supercap?

Comment: It acts as an energy storage unit, like a battery. It is supposed to store energy when my main source provides more power that the load consumes, and to provide energy when the load needs a greater power that that provided by the main power source.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. Replacing a super-capacitor with a current source make no sense.

Comment: Capacitor equivalent source is a voltage source

Comment: There are two completely different circuits. In the second one, the current source acts as the load, it does not model a supercap (read the description of the second circuit again). The second circuit has no supercap, the load is the current source, and the extra resistor is there in order to consume the extra energy provided by the main power source. I managed to make the second circuit to work, I just had to increase the capacitance of C1 and the oscillations were eliminated.